# C# Why can't I find DataGridView in my toolbox?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I would like to use the DataGridView from my Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. But my toolbox does not have DataGridView, it only has GridView. Why is that so? Please help. Thanks so much.

Comment: `DataGridView` control is a winforms control. `GridView` is web server control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGridView is Windows Control. You cant use it in Web application:

**GridView** 
The GridView control is the successor to the DataGrid control. Like the DataGrid control, the GridView control was designed to display data in an HTML table. When bound to a data source, the DataGrid and GridView controls each display a row from a DataSource as a row in an output table.

**DataGrid**

Both the DataGrid and GridView controls are derived from the WebControl class. Although it has a similar object model to that of the DataGrid control, the GridView control also has a number of new features and advantages over the DataGrid control, which include:

Refer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05yye6k9.aspx

Comment: Yes you can use GridView only in Web Application or else you need to go for third party contols.. Hope this help

Comment: I'm not seeing it either, and I'm working in a WPF application project.